# Building web dashboards using django

Tags: python, django, dashboard

I want to build a web page that should contain some charts(bar, line, pie,etc.).I know the basics of Django. (i.e) how to create an app, model and other kinds of stuff. I have gone through Charts.js, fusion charts on google. But I cannot figure out how to build a dashboard with my data in MySQL database. Is it possible to create web dashboards using the data from the database (and also from excel files)? If so please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Vicky, this is all possible, but the question is a bit too broad to be answered on StackOverflow. If you want to use data from your database on the front-end, you'll need to make view functions in Django that access data, process it, and pass that along to the client-side. There's a lot of bases to cover here, but you can get it done. Maybe check out how [this library](https://github.com/geex-arts/django-jet) works

Answer (score 1):

you can look at [dash](https://dash.plot.ly), it's an easy py framework specialized in build web apps with charts, [here](https://tomaztsql.wordpress.com/2018/06/18/real-time-data-visualization-with-sql-server-and-python-dash/) is one of the ways you can use to connect your database with your app